# Scala: Pattern match multiple Option arguments

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I would like to achieve something like the following:

```
  private def msgPrefix(implicit myClass: MyClass, anotherClass: AnotherClass) = {        
    Option(myClass, anotherClass) match {
      case Some(validMyClass, validAnotherClass) => validMyClass.process + validAnotherClass.process
      case _       => ""
    }
  }
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what you're looking for, but :

```
 private def msgPrefix(implicit myClass: MyClass, anotherClass: AnotherClass) = {        
   (Option(myClass), Option(anotherClass)) match {
     case (Some(validMyClass), Some(validAnotherClass)) => validMyClass.process + validAnotherClass.process
     case _ => ""
   }
 }
```

This will return the empty String if at least one of the two arguments is null, ie :

```
scala> msgPrefix(MyClass("foo"),null)
res2: String = ""

scala> msgPrefix(MyClass("foo"),AnotherClass("bar"))
res3: String = foobar
```

But you probably should just change the type of the arguments to `Option[MyClass]` and `Option[AnotherClass]` (if you can).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Marth that your arguments should probably be `Option[MyClass]` and `Option[AnotherClass]`. But to answer your original question, you can use a for comprehension rather than pattern matching:

```
private def msgPrefix(implicit myClass: MyClass, anotherClass: AnotherClass) = {
  val prefix = for {
    validMyClass <- Option(myClass)
    validAnotherClass <- Option(anotherClass)
  } yield validMyClass.process + validAnotherClass.process
  prefix.getOrElse("")
}
```

Comment: I really like this solution but I accepted @Marth answer as that was what I was looking for.